# How do you read and understand this bitshifting code?

Tags: javascript, bit-manipulation

So I [found](https://github.com/inolen/bit-buffer/blob/master/bit-buffer.js) some "bit buffer" code in JavaScript which should help me out on my journey to, well, write a bit buffer (only I'm doing it in a different language).

I took the key parts of the code and pasted it here (for LittleEndian only):

```
function LittleEndianView(size) {
  Object.defineProperty(this, 'native', {
    value: new Uint8Array(size)
  })
}

LittleEndianView.prototype.get = function(bits, offset) {
  let available = (this.native.length * 8 - offset)

  if (bits > available) {
    throw new Error('Range error')
  }

  let value = 0
  let i = 0
  // why loop through like this?
  while (i < bits) {
    // remaining bits
    const remaining = bits - i
    const bitOffset = offset & 7
    const currentByte = this.native[offset >> 3]

    const read = Math.min(remaining, 8 - bitOffset)

    const a = 0xFF << read
    mask = ~a
    const b = currentByte >> bitOffset
    readBits = b & mask

    const c = readBits << i

    value = value | c
    offset += read
    i += read
  }

  return value >>> 0
}

LittleEndianView.prototype.set = function(bits, offset) {
  const available = (this.native.length * 8 - offset)

  if (bits > available) {
    throw new Error('Range error')
  }

  let i = 0
  while (i < bits) {
    const remaining = bits - i
    const bitOffset = offset & 7
    const byteOffset = offset >> 3
    const finished = Math.min(remaining, 8 - bitOffset)

    const mask = ~(0xFF << finished)
    const writeBits = value & mask
    const value >>= finished

    const destMask = ~(mask << bitOffset)
    const byte = this.view[byteOffset]

    this.native[byteOffset] = (byte & destMask) | (writeBits << bitOffset)

    offset += finished
    i += finished
  }
}
```

I would like help on the comments, on what each piece means. It seems there are a lot of bit manipulation tricks that I am not aware of. For example, if I search google for "bitshift right" or "bitshift left", I get the obvious answer of shifting right or left. But *why* did they do the bitshift right there, with that number? Why did they negate that number? Why did they & or | that number?

I am trying to go through this code line by line and comment it out, but I am struggling writing comments because I don't know why they are applying the bitshift operations when they do.

So my main question is, how do you go about reading this bitshifting code and know *why* the bitshift is performed? I am going to want to be reading how [md5](https://github.com/jpcanepa/md5js/blob/master/md5js.js) and other way more complex hash algorithms and image processing algorithms and other "bit" algorithms work, but first I think I need to know when to *apply* the bitshift operators, because just knowing how they work doesn't help much.

As a deeper question, perhaps this could be answered here... If you are given bit manipulation code without comments or good variable names, how do you figure out what it's doing?

Sidenote, is there a book or something that lists all the common bit tricks? I have seen [this](https://gist.github.com/stephenLee/4024869) and others, but they are all very short.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bit_manipulation#Further_reading and https://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html should get you started. But surely you know that asking for references is off-topic on SO?

Comment: To understand the "why", I'd suggest trying to implement the function yourself. It's documented well [what it does](https://github.com/inolen/bit-buffer), so just consider how you would solve it. What do the data structures look like? What data do you want to get from where to where? The code is quite readable actually.

Comment: @Bergi check it out, making progress! https://github.com/lancejpollard/bit.js/blob/master/test.js Inspired by your comment.